# Flutter checkbox unwanted touch space

Tags: checkbox, dart, flutter

I tried to create a login screen using flutter, there I added remember me checkbox, but I could not align it correctly,

Flutter checkbox took unwanted space around itself, for the provide good touch user experience.

This is the how my layout show,

[image]

Check below code,

```
        new Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Checkbox(
                        activeColor: Colors.grey,
                        value: _isChecked,
                        onChanged: (bool value) {
                          _onChecked(value);
                        },
                      ),
                      new GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () => print("Remember me"),
                        child: new Text(
                          "Remember me",
                          style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white70),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  new Text(
                    "Forgot password ?",
                    style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white70),
                  )
                ],
              ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT

**Short Answer**

```
Checkbox(
   materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
    ...
 )
```

..................

**Long Answer**

You can achieve this by customising the Checkbox widget.

1. Create a CustomCheckbox using the exact code from
   *flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/checkbox.dart*.
2. Add a new field to your CustomCheckbox widget

   ```
        final bool useTapTarget;
   ```
3. Make sure to add the new field to your constructor with it default
   value set to true.

   ```
        this.useTapTarget = true
   ```
4. Modify the build method in the *_CheckboxState* method. Add this
   block of code above the return call.

   ```
        Size noTapTargetSize = Size(CustomCheckbox.width, 
        CustomCheckbox.width);
        final BoxConstraints additionalConstraints = 
        BoxConstraints.tight(widget
           .useTapTarget? size : noTapTargetSize);
   ```
5. Finally, use your CustomCheckbox widget in your code, and set your
   custom field to false to remove material padding. example

   ```
   Container(
           margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
           child:CustomCheckbox(
               value: _checked,
               materialTapTargetSize: null,
               onChanged: _onCheckBoxChange,
               useTapTarget: false,
               activeColor: Colors.teal),
         )
   ```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: how would you do this with the latest flutter checkbox?

Comment: try this @blah

Checkbox(
   materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
    ...
 )

Answer (score 10):

**Use SizedBox**

The widget is basically made for resizing its child.

```
SizedBox(
    width: 15,
    height: 15,
    child: Checkbox(value: false, onChanged: null)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this then,

[image: demo]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'NonStopIO',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.red,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _rememberMeFlag = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('NonStopIO'),
      ),
      body: new Container(
        color: Colors.black38,
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Container(
              margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0, horizontal: 35.0),
              color: Colors.white70,
              height: 50.0,
            ),
            new Container(
              margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0, horizontal: 35.0),
              color: Colors.white70,
              height: 50.0,
            ),
            new Container(
                margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0, horizontal: 20.0),
                child: new Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new GestureDetector(
                          child: new Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              new Checkbox(
                                value: _rememberMeFlag,
                                onChanged: (value) => setState(() {
                                      _rememberMeFlag = !_rememberMeFlag;
                                    }),
                              ),
                              new Text(
                                "Remember me",
                                style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white70),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                          onTap: () => setState(() {
                                _rememberMeFlag = !_rememberMeFlag;
                              }),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    new Container(
                      margin: new EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.0),
                      child: new Text(
                        "Forgot password ?",
                        style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white70),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                )),
            new Container(
              margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0, horizontal: 35.0),
              color: Colors.orange,
              height: 50.0,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Here, I have adjusted the **margin** to align the Checkbox and  Forgot password Text.

Comment: What is the essential part of the answer? Can't find a difference in the result except the colors.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Do you want to align the checkbox with the TextField vertically?

Comment: It's not my question, but yes, I think this is what the question is about.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Updated the Answer

Comment: This is not the solution though. It's just a workaround.

Comment: @AjayKumar Yes, I want to align the checkbox with the TextField vertically... but the problem in your code is,  it seems like you used different horizontal margins, but I want to do this without using margin or padding.

Comment: @SachinthaUdara, In that case, you can make a custom checkbox using this file flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/checkbox.dart .

Comment: @AjayKumar Thank, I`ll check